# Algorithm for transforming all left-recursive rules in a grammar into direct left-recursive

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

*I'm probably missing a lot of terminology here, so I'll try to rather be too clear than too vague.*

I have a Context-Free grammar as an input, that might contain direct or indirect left-recursion between some of the rules. Identifying the recursion is not too hard, can be done with a graph traversal algorithm. We simply create a directed graph, where the vertices are the rules, and each rule $A$ points at $B$, if $A$ has a production rule in the form $A \to B \alpha$. Since I know no better name, let's call it the left-call-graph.

Each cycle on this graph shows left-recursion, loops are direct, longer cycles are indirect.

I would like an equivalent transformation, so that each rule that participates in an indirect recursion (by being a part of a cycle in this graph) would get transformed into direct left-recursion (so that all cycles would become loops). **Note, that I know about Paull's Algorithm**, but to my understanding, that only makes the graph acyclic, but there will be still paths between the different rules that were in a cycle previously. My goal is to make each indirect left-recursive case into a direct one.

**Also note**, that I'm not sure such algorithm even could exists.

Comment: A possible approach would be the contraction of several rules similar to the elimination of chain rules in the construction of Chomsky-Normal-Form, for example.

If the grammar has the rules:
$$A\rightarrow B\alpha, B\rightarrow A\beta  | C\gamma$$
you eliminate the first one and introduce the new rules
$$A\rightarrow  A\beta\alpha  | C\gamma\alpha$$
which compact the sequential application of two rules into one. The corresponding left recursion on $B$ disappears 'automatically.'